# How to set a border color of whole QTableWidget, not items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qtablewidget

I am struggling with the issue that I am not able to set a border color to a QTableWidget so it would only **formate the very surrounding** of the widget.

Following commands did not help `setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{ border-color: green}")` does nothing and
`setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{ border: 1px solid green})` results in "over formatting" as you can see in the attached image

Formated image:
[image: Formated image]

I do not wish to formate the headers. I searched for a while and could not find any solution. Does anybody know how to handle it in Python source code or in QT Designer?

Comment: What version of PyQt5 are you using? I replicated the example and the `border` property appears as expected https://prnt.sc/vihdth

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting a stylesheet somewhere else too?

Comment: @alec I am using PyQt5 version 5.15.0.

Comment: @musicamante I am not setting a stylesheet somewhere else. I originally used Qt Designer for my dialogue with default empty styles setStyleSheet("") .